# Sorting continuous variables by dummy categories in R

Tags: r, if-statement, countif

I have an `income` variable which contains income information for the categorical variable `races` where `races=1` is White and `races=2` is Black. I am trying to figure out a way of seeing how many blacks in my data set make over 316000. I know how to do this in Stata by simply

```
 sort races income
 by races: count if income>316000
```

However, I am struggling in R. I tried

```
x<-table(income,races)
x[(x>316000) if races==2]
```

but get an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you rarely (perhaps never) need to sort your data. Consider something like:

```
table(races[income > 316000])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
x[x$income > 316000 & x$races == 2,]
```

Comment: I got an error message with this but Thomas's suggestion worked. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Other possibilities, assuming your data frame is named `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(income = c(316000, 316000, 316000, 316000, 316001, 316001),
             race = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
df
#   income race
# 1 316000    1
# 2 316000    1
# 3 316000    1
# 4 316000    2
# 5 316001    2
# 6 316001    2

with(df, sum(income[race == 2] > 316000))
# [1] 2

# or 
with(df, sum(income > 316000 & race == 2))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: I tried this but got 0 values. Another suggestion worked for my code. Many thanks!